# Gatling Scenario Response time

Tags: scala, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

I am doing load test for an api which average response time is 5 sec

in my script i setup constantUserPerSecond  2 and duration 150 second

`.inject(constantUsersPerSec(2) during (150 seconds)),`

will it generate 2 request per second ? or less , because of 1 request will take 5 second to complete ?

Comment: Why not simply run that code and see what happens?

Comment: yes, i run it but not getting  expected QA for a 150 second. so i just want understand how  constantUsersPerSec() method works internally. but could not found any documentation.

Comment: You haven't found https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/src/sphinx/general/simulation_setup.rst? In that repository, you can simply check the source code to see what happens

Comment: got it. Thanks for sharing. i will check the source code.

Answer (score 0):

constantUsersPerSec(2) will start a new user executing the scenario every .5 seconds or so. For this sort of injection profile gatling doesn't take into consideration how long it takes for a request to complete.

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes, i also thought so. but i am not getting expected qps after some times. actually i run the same script in parallel  from 5 process for 3 minutes. and expecting 5*2 =10 qps for 3 minutes. but actual qps i am getting is not consistent.